# ERROR en array de strings dentro de una estructura c++

Tags: c++

Pongamos como ejemplo el siguiente:

Una sala de cine pone a la venta los abonos de temporada. Cada abono corresponde a un asiento de la sala al cual el socio podría acudir durante toda la temporada. En la sala existen 25 filas de 20 asientos cada una.

Por cada asiento habría que almacenar el nombre del abonado y si ese asiento esta libre o no para su compra.

He pensado en lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int Fil=25;
const int Col=20;
typedef array <string,Fil> TFila;
typedef array <TFila,Col> TFila_asiento; // array de strings locooo!!

struct TSalaCine{
    TFila_asiento Fila_asiento; //array de string asiento y fila
    string abonado;
}; 

int main(){

}

void asientos_libres(TSalaCine &sala){
    for(int fila=0; fila<25; fila++){
        for(int col=0;col<20; col++){
            sala.Fila_asiento[fila][col]='0';
        }
    }
    
}
```

¿Es posible hacer un array de strings, es decir que en cada posición del array lo que yo almacene sea un string?

En caso afirmativo, como relleno ese string para inicializarlo como conjunto vacío, he probado con poner de valor en el bucle for `'0'`, pero no funciona.

El objetivo que tengo en mente es primero inicializar a 0 (conjunto vacío) el array de strings, y luego pedir al usuario el nombre del cliente e insertarlo en el lugar del respectivo sitio.

El problema es que cuando voy a comparar si el sitio esta vacio o no `if(sala.Fila_asiento[fila][col]=='\0')` me sale el siguiente error:

> ejercicio3.cpp:48:36: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types
> are ‘std::arraystd::__cxx11::basic_string<char, 25ul>::value_type
> {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}’ and ‘char’)
> if(sala.Fila_asiento[fila][col]=='\0'){
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/iosfwd:40:0,
> from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:38,
> from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
> from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
> from ejercicio3.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/6/bits/postypes.h:216:5: note: candidate:
> template bool std::operator==(const
> std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)
> operator==(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)

Gracias por la respuesta. Un saludo :D

Comment: No le veo ningún sentido a que en la estructura que representa la sala de cine, tengas una variable `string` que se llame `abonado`. ¿Y el resto de abonados? Para representar esto no necesitas más que una matriz de `string`, una por asiento. Si tienen nombre, tienen abonado. Si está vacía, no tienen abonado.

Answer (score 3):

El error no tiene nada que ver con el array de `string` dentro de una estructura. Obtendrías exáctamente el mismo error fuera de una estructura:

> ```
> error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::array<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, 25ul>::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ and ‘char’)
> if(sala.Fila_asiento[fila][col]=='\0'){
> ```

Para empezar, parece que no compartes el código que genera el error. En el error indica que estás usando el operador de comparación `‘operator==’`, en tu código muestras el operador de asignación:

```
for(int fila=0; fila<25; fila++){
    for(int col=0;col<20; col++){
        sala.Fila_asiento[fila][col]='0';
//                  Asignación ---> ^
    }
}
```

El código que muestras no da fallo alguno. Si en lugar de una asignación fuese una comparación ¿Qué significaría el error?

- `error: no match for ‘operator==’`: No hay coincidencia para el operador de comparación.
- `(operand types are ‘std::array<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, 25ul>::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ and ‘char’)`: Los operandos son `TFila::value_type` (que es un `std::string`) y `char`.

Es decir, estás comparando una cadena (`std::string`) con un carácter (`char`), podemos ver que [este operador tiene dos sobrecargas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp):

```
constexpr bool operator==( const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs ) noexcept;
constexpr bool operator==( const std::string& lhs, const CharT* rhs );
```

Y ninguna de las sobrecargas compara una cadena con un carácter, de ahí el error.

---

Respecto a tus dudas:

> ¿Es posible hacer un array de strings, es decir que en cada posición del array lo que yo almacene sea un string?

Por supuesto, en tu caso no estás haciendo eso si no un `std::array` de `std::array` de `std::string`, pero el concepto es el mismo. Podrías aplicar las siguientes mejoras a tu diseño:

1. Transforma el objeto sala en una plantilla y Parametriza sus filas y columnas.
2. Define los alias de tipos internamente en el objeto sala.
3. Usa alias tipo C++11.

```
template <auto Fil, auto Col>
struct TSalaCine{
    using TFila = array<string,Fil>;
    using TFila_asiento<TFila,Col>;
    TFila_asiento Fila_asiento; //array de string asiento y fila
}; 

// Cine con 25 filas y 20 columnas:
using cine_25x20 = TSalaCine<25, 20>;
```

> ¿Cómo relleno ese string para inicializarlo como conjunto vacío?

No tienes que hacer nada, por defecto los `std::string` se construyen vacíos. Puedes comprobar si un elemento está vacío llamando a `std::string::empty`:

```
if (sala.Fila_asiento[fila][col].empty()){
```

Answer (score 2):

> Es posible hacer un array de strings, es decir que en cada posicion del array lo que yo almacene sea un string??

Si es posible, de hecho, es lo que estas haciendo

> En caso afirmativo, como relleno ese string para inicializarlo como conjunto vació, he probado con poner de valor en el bucle for '0', pero no funciona.

El valor '0' es de tipo `char`, no es un string. Lo que va a hacer es converirlo en "0". Para inciarlo como vacio puedes ponerlo asi `= ""`

> El problema es que cuando voy a comparar si el sitio esta vacio o no `if(sala.Fila_asiento[fila][col]=='\0')` me sale el siguiente error:

Si lees el error, dice que esta implementada una forma de comparar un `std::string` con un `char`. Si lo quieres hacer de esa manera, te recomendaria sobrecargar el `operator==`. Tambien es de hacer notar que el caracter `0`, el que le asignaste a los asientos, tiene un valor numerico de 48, y el caracter `\0` tiene uno de 0.

#### Una propuesta

Hasta donde entiendo, tienes que llevar la cuenta de los nombres de las personas, y llevar cuenta de los asientos libres.

Si quieres mantener el array solo con strings, yo lo que te recomendaría es tener un `std::string` que signifique que el asiento no tiene dueño. Asi, si tiene un string diferente, en este caso el nombre, sabemos que no esta ocupado.

Por ejemplo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Tiene que ser algo que no te puedan poner como nombre por accidente
const string vacio = "jdklf";


const int Fil=25;
const int Col=20;
typedef array <string,Fil> TFila;
typedef array <TFila,Col> TFila_asiento; // array de strings locooo!!

struct TSalaCine{
    TFila_asiento Fila_asiento; //array de string asiento y fila
    string abonado;
}; 

int main(){

}

void asientos_libres(TSalaCine &sala){
    for(int fila=0; fila<25; fila++){
        for(int col=0;col<20; col++){
            sala.Fila_asiento[fila][col]=vacio;
        }
    }
    
}
```

En este caso revisas si `if(sala.Fila_asiento[fila][col]==vacio)`

#### Mi propuesta

Yo lo que te recomendaría, es asi como tienes el `TFila_asiento` de strings, tengas uno de booleanos (ponlos por default en falso). Asi la revicion sera mas rápida, nos ahorramos un monton de copias innecesarias y de paso te ahorras escribir la funcion `asientos_libres`

**Solicitud:** Si lo haces de esta manera, puedes poner asi como pusiste en el array de stings? Solo que en vez de `// array de strings locooo!!` pones un `// array de bools locooo!! Wuuuuu !!`?

Un saludo :D

Answer (score 2):

El constructor por defecto de `std::string` crea un string *vacio*, por lo que por ahí no hay ningún problema.

Para comprobar si un `std::string` está *vacío*, no tienes mas que usar su función-miembro `empty( )`:

```
std::string test;

std::cout << test.empty( ) << '\n';
```

> 1

```
std::string test;
test = "A ver que pasa ... ";

std::cout << test.empty( ) << '\n';
```

> 0

Si en algún momento quieres eliminar el contenido de un `std::string` y volver a dejarlo *vacío*, no tienes mas que llamar a su función-miembro `clear( )`:

```
std::string test;
test = "A ver que pasa ... ";

std::cout << test.empty( ) << '\n';

test.clear( );

std::cout << test.empty( ) << '\n';
```

> 0
> 1